# Filter for array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter an array if the array includes some array too.

Here's the data:

```js
let data = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
let to_filter = [2, 5]
```

I want to filter the data array if the elements of array inside it includes elements in to_filter array.
So the expected output is

```js
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Is this possible? Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Could you just use a couple of for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> Here I am checking if `to_filter` contains any element of the subarray if not filter out that subarray

```js
const data = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
const to_filter = [2, 5]

const output = data.filter(
    subArray => subArray.some(x => to_filter.includes(x))
)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, work like a charm. My approachment is close like this.
`const output = data.filter(subArray => subArray.some(city_id => tracker.includes(city_id) ) } );` Just realized that I had a typo.